# Django user activated apps on site

Tags: python, django

What would be the best approach to implement functionality that can be added or removed depending on the users preferences? What i am trying to do is to have a standard set of apps/functionality for all registered users and allow users to add any extra apps they would like from a list of the ones provided. As stated in the question this is django specific question. However, any information on how this is achieved in any other language will be very helpful. I'm sure there is a lot of information out there since it's very similar to adding apps on facebook.

Comment: It is nothing like adding apps on Facebook.

Comment: I know it's nothing like apps on facebook. my question is how would you implement something to similar to the apps on facebook, particularly the ones built by facebook and not provided by third parties.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused between django apps (used to split up projects into parts with similar purpose) and a facebook app which is more like a program/widget.

Are you trying to create a platform that allows developers to create apps, or will you be creating all the apps?

Django has a built in permissions model that works with the built in django authentication.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#methods, you can create a new permission for each app.  Assign that permission to users that are allowed to interact with your app. And check for the permission before allowing a user to use the app.
There are also apps that allow for object level permissions.

Comment: The fact that idiom "app" is used in Django terminologymakes this a very difficult problem to google. The idea is that it is not necessary that every user be able to create every object type (objects models). So I'm trying to figure out a way to allow users to "install" and "uninstall" apps as you would on facebook for example. The intent is to create the apps  and if all goes well open up to allow others create apps via an API.